# TSQL Select without extra text

Tags: t-sql, select

I have a column in the data base that stores the data like

//item
//item//item3
//text
//item//item3//item 10

Is there a way to select this as

/item
/item/item3
/text
//item/item3/item10

*note the spaces are removed.

Thank you in advanced?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your example, I assume that you want to replace the double slashes with single slashes, and remove spaces that are not in front of a slash. (And that the double slash that is not replaced is a mistake.)

You can use replaces to do that:

```
replace(replace(replace(replace(col, '//', '/'), ' /', '//'), ' ', ''), '//', ' /')
```

Note: This won't work properly if you have /// somewhere in the data.

Comment: Yes! That was perfect!  Thank you very, very very much.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this in T-SQL:-

```
select replace(col1, ' ', '') as your_col...
```

if you want to remove spaces: this can be adjusted to remove tabs, carriage returns and lines feeds by using

```
REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(MyField, CHAR(10), ''), CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(9), '')
```

but the formating of your example makes things less than 100% clear: do you want to remove spaces or specific characters or both?